# Not same height menu bar in chrome, firefox and ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I've been working on a site with a top menu bar. In Chrome it works like a charm, but when I open it on Firefox or IE the height of the sub menus aren't the correct size. Link to website: *Old link removed*. I've also made a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YF7GG/1/) . I've searched for it on different places and the most say the same thing: impossible to fix because of different browsers. Is this also in my case or is it there a stupid fault in it somewhere?

Code of CSS:

```
@charset"utf-8";
.centreer {
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    position: relative;
    height:auto;
}
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
    float: right;
}
.menu_tekst li {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    max-height:52px;
    height:52px;
    text-height:52px;
}
.menu_tekst li.titel_blok ul.sub li.titel_blok_sub .link_titel {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    max-height:52px;
    height:52px;
    text-height:52px;
}
.onder_menu {
    height:52px;
}
.link_titel {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:15px 10px 16px 10px;
    color:#444;
    background-color:none;
}
.actief {
    background-color:#444;
    color:#999;
}
.menu_tekst li:hover > a.link_titel {
    color:#999;
    background-color:#444;
}
.tussenstuk {
    background-color:none;
    height:30px;
    width:5px;
}
.logo {
    position:absolute;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    border:none !important;
}
.sub_menu {
    height:52px !important;
    background-color:#444;
}
.menu_tekst ul.sub_bannen {
    width:1000px;
    margin:32px 0 0 0;
    left:-173px;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    display:none;
}
.menu_tekst ul.sub_kalender {
    width:1000px;
    margin:32px 0 0 0;
    left:-215px;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    display:none;
}
.menu_tekst ul.sub_media {
    width:1000px;
    margin:32px 0 0 0;
    left:0px;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    display:none;
}
ul.sub_media .link_titel, ul.sub_kalender .link_titel, ul.sub_bannen .link_titel {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:16px 10px 16px 10px;
    color:#999;
    background-color:#444;
}
li {
    max-height:20px !important;
}
ul.sub_media li.titel_blok_sub:hover > a.link_titel, ul.sub_bannen li.titel_blok_sub:hover > a.link_titel, ul.sub_kalender li.titel_blok_sub:hover > a.link_titel {
    color:#979176 !important;
}
li.bannen:hover > ul.sub_bannen, li.media:hover > ul.sub_media, li.kalender:hover > ul.kalender {
    display:block !important;
}
li.bannen.actief > ul, li.media.actief > ul, li.kalender.actief > ul {
    display:block;
}
.sub .actief {
    color:#979176 !important;
}
.titel_blok:hover > .sub {
    display:block;
}
.menu_tekst > .actief > .sub {
    display:block;
}
.menu_tekst:hover > .actief > .sub {
    display:none;
}
.menu_tekst:hover > .actief:hover > .sub {
    display:block;
}
.sub_media ul.sub_sub_fotos, .sub_media ul.sub_sub_formulieren, .sub_media ul.sub_sub_bestanden {
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#AAA;
    height:36px;
    margin:16px 0 0 0;
    padding:16px 0 0 0;
    left:0px;
    float:left;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
}
.sub_media ul.sub_sub_fotos li.space_left {
    margin-left:140px;
}
.sub_media ul.sub_sub_bestanden li.space_left_bestanden {
    margin-left:10px;
}
ul.sub_sub_fotos .link_titel, ul.sub_sub_formulieren .link_titel, ul.sub_sub_bestanden .link_titel {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:16px 10px 16px 10px;
    color:#444;
    background-color:#AAA;
}
li.fotos:hover > ul.sub_sub_fotos, li.formulieren:hover > ul.sub_sub_formulieren, li.bestanden:hover > ul.sub_sub_bestanden {
    display:block !important;
}
ul.sub_sub_fotos li:hover > a.link_titel, ul.sub_sub_formulieren li:hover > a.link_titel, ul.sub_sub_bestanden li:hover > a.link_titel {
    background-color:#AAA !important;
    color:#000 !important;
}
li.fotos.actief > ul, li.formulieren.actief > ul, li.bestanden.actief > ul {
    display:block !important;
}
.titel_blok_sub:hover > .sub_sub {
    display:block;
}
.sub > .actief > .sub_sub {
    display:block;
}
.sub:hover > .actief > .sub_sub {
    display:none !important;
}
.sub:hover > .actief:hover > .sub_sub {
    display:block !important;
}
.sub_sub_fotos .actief, .sub_sub_formulieren .actief, .sub_sub_bestanden .actief {
    color:#000 !important;
}
```

Code of HTML:

```
<div class="centreer">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <div class="menu_b">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.php"><img width="375" height="52px" title="Home" src="afbeeldingen/menu/logo.gif"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu_tekst">
            <li class="titel_blok"><a class="link_titel" href="faq.php">Faq</a></li>
            <li class="tussenstuk"></li>
            <li class="titel_blok"><a class="link_titel" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="tussenstuk"></li>
            <li class="titel_blok media"><a class="link_titel" href="media.php">Media</a>
                <ul class="sub_media sub">
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub formulieren"><a class="link_titel" href="media/formulieren.php">Formulieren</a>
                        <ul class="sub_sub_formulieren sub_sub">
                            <li class="space_left_formulieren">&nbsp;</li>
                            <li><a class="link_titel" href="media/formulieren.php#fiche">Medische fiche</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub bestanden"><a class="link_titel" href="media/bestanden.php">Bestanden</a>
                        <ul class="sub_sub_bestanden sub_sub">
                            <li class="space_left_bestanden">&nbsp;</li>
                            <li><a class="link_titel" href="media/bestanden.php#algemeen">Algemene brieven</a></li>
                            <li><a class="link_titel" href="media/bestanden.php#pioniers">Pioniers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub fotos"><a class="link_titel" href="media/fotos.php">Foto's</a>
                        <ul class="sub_sub_fotos sub_sub">
                            <li class="space_left">&nbsp;</li>
                            <li><a class="link_titel" href="media/fotos/2013_2014.php">2013-2014</a></li>
                            <li><a class="link_titel" href="media/fotos/2012_2013.php">2012-2013</a></li>
                            <li><a class="link_titel" href="media/fotos/kamp/kampfotos.php">Kampfoto's</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub filmpje"><a class="link_titel" href="media/filmpje.php">Leidingsfilmpje</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="tussenstuk"></li>
            <li class="titel_blok kalender actief"><a class="link_titel actief" href="kalender.php">Kalender</a>
                <ul class="sub_kalender sub">
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub"><a class="link_titel" href="quiz/eindscore.php">Eindscore Quiz</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="tussenstuk"></li>
            <li class="titel_blok bannen"><a class="link_titel" href="bannen.php">Bannen</a>
                <ul class="sub_bannen sub">
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub"><a class="link_titel" href="bannen/plusachttien.php">+18</a></li>
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub"><a class="link_titel" href="bannen/pluszestien.php">+16</a></li>
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub"><a class="link_titel" href="bannen/sjo.php">Sjo</a></li>
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub"><a class="link_titel" href="bannen/knim.php">Knim</a></li>
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub"><a class="link_titel" href="bannen/joros.php">Joro's</a></li>
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub"><a class="link_titel" href="bannen/grovers.php">Grovers</a></li>
                    <li class="titel_blok_sub"><a class="link_titel" href="bannen/piepers.php">Piepers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="tussenstuk"></li>
            <li class="titel_blok"><a class="link_titel" href="info.php">Info</a></li>
            <li class="tussenstuk"></li>
            <li class="titel_blok"><a class="link_titel" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="onder_menu">
    </div>
    <div class="sub_menu">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw an overflow on your menu, if you mean that telling "menus are not correct size", then you should check your sub menu's link element.

Your link element has

```
padding: 16px 10px 16px 10px;
```

Change this to

```
padding: 16px 10px 12px 10px;
```

Chrome and firefox looking same on my mac.

Comment: Not working for me, then in chrome the 'a-box' is to small, so if you wan't to go to the sub, sub menu, it disappear. The black border is gone then in Firefox, but there is still an empty space between the menus. Is it the same with the JSFiddle, or directly from the website?

Comment: Same on website, JSFiddle and same on both browsers, chrome and firefox.

Comment: I agree with Canser, they changing the padding makes it the same in IE, etc.

Comment: Now I had the time the check the menu again it turns out that you were  right, just had to change the right paddings! Thanks!